# How does mysql execute or interpret a subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, mysql-workbench

I need to understand how mysql interprets or executes such a subquery:

```
SELECT SUM(tp),SUM(ep),SUM(mp) FROM
(
    SELECT Avg(case date_format(PS_DATE,'%Y') when '2005' then nvl(tp,0) else 0 end) tp,   
           Avg(case date_format(PS_DATE,'%Y') when '2005' then nvl(ep,0) else 0 end) ep, 
           Avg(case date_format(PS_DATE,'%Y') when '2005' then nvl(mp,0) else 0 end) mp   
    FROM M_DAILY 
    WHERE PS_DATE >= date ('2005-01-01') and PS_DATE <= date ('2005-12-31');
) As T
```

Can someone interpret how such a query is interpreted (in words)please!

Answer (score 0):

For the year 2005, it finds the SUM of average values of the columns tp, ep and mp. While doing this null values are considered as 0. As the dates are filtered for year 2005, the above code can be simplified as

```
SELECT SUM(tp),SUM(ep),SUM(mp) FROM
(
    SELECT Avg(nvl(tp,0)) tp,   
           Avg(nvl(ep,0)) ep,   
           Avg(nvl(mp,0)) mp           
    FROM M_DAILY 
    WHERE PS_DATE >= date ('2005-01-01') and PS_DATE <= date ('2005-12-31');
) As T
```

Comment: okay, lemme ask: what is the outer query[select sum(tp)...] doing to the inner query?

Comment: The inner query finds the average and outer query finds the SUM. But since the averages are no grouped by, you will get the same result both in inner and outer queries

Comment: so mysql runs the inner query first and finds the averages based on the where clause and from that result, it finds the sum of those averages! right or wrong??